# Dynamically build predicate

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, expression, predicate

I have a method like

```
public static int Update<TEntity>(
            this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
            Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> updateExpression)
            where TEntity : class
        {
.....
....}
```

Calling above is pretty simple.

```
context.Products
    .Where(x => x.UnitInStock == 0)
    .Update(x => new Product() { Discontinued = true && UnitInStock = 10}
```

I have a senario where i have to build the predicate dynamically as i do not know which field to pass inside predicate:

```
x => new Product() { Discontinued = true && UnitInStock = 10}
```

How can i build this predicate dynamically and pass to Update extension method.

Like

```
GetPredicate(IQueryable<TEntity> source, List<strings> fields, List<string> values)
```

which will return

```
x => new Product() { Discontinued = true && UnitInStock = 10}
```

Comment: `.Update()` is not a standard method of LINQ or .NET.  You'll need to be more specific on whose implementation you are using.

Comment: Are you talking about dynamic expressions? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Comment: First of all, `x => new Product() { Discontinued = true && UnitInStock = 10}` is not a valid construct. Second, it's not a predicate. Third, I have no idea what it is or supposed to be. Please update your question.

Comment: @IvanStoev It looks like a valid construct to me.  It doesn't look like a *sensible* one, but it should compile.

Comment: @Servy Oh, you mean soimething like Product.Discontinued = true && (UnitsInStock = 10); where UnitsInStock is an external variable?! Omg :-) I doubt OP had such in mind though. Hmm, now when I'm thinking, even this one looks invalid to me, I'm curious what do you have in mind.

Comment: @IvanStoev Like I said, legal, but not sensible ;)

Comment: I am going to use https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended for batch update actually. See their example:                            context.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.StatusId == 1)
    .Update(t => new Task { StatusId = 2 })                                                                                                               In my case StatusId could be anyother property like Discontinued, UnitsInStock and so on.